# Probability Density Function- Expected value of Benefit

Tags: probability

An insurance policy reimburses a loss up to a benefit limit of 10. The policy holders loss, Y, follows a distribution with PDF:

$$f(y)=\begin{cases} \frac{2}{y^3} & y > 1 \\ 0 & else \end{cases}$$

$E[x]= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \frac{2}{y^3}$

$\int_1^{10} \frac{2}{y^2}$

$\frac{2}{y} \Big\vert_1^{10}=\frac{1}{5}-\frac{10}{5}$

Of course this answer cannot be correct.

Comment: What is the indefinite integral of $y^{-2}?$ Watch signs.

Comment: Your mistake is in the antiderivative, this should be $\frac{-2}{y}$.